# Problema con funcion en node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo la función x y quiero llamar en esta función a obtener_letras pero siempre retorna undefined, en el console.log('respuesta: '+info.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body)
si imprime bien. Como debería obtener el dato: info.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body de obtener_letras?

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

funcion x(){

letra = obtener_letras('xxxxx')

}

function obtener_letras(q_track){
    // Construcicon del cuerpo del mensaje
    let inputs = {
        "apikey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "q_track": q_track
    }
    request({
        "uri": "https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.lyrics.get",
        "method": "GET",
        "qs": inputs
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err) {
          var info = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log('respuesta: '+info.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body);
          return info.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body; //retorna undefined
        } else {
          console.error("No se puedo conectar al API - MUSIXMATCH:" + err);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Tu funcion no retorna nada

Comment: Te falta ponerle return al final de tu funcion obtener_letras con lo que quieras que te devuelva

Comment: si al final pongo return info.message.body.lyrics.lyrics_body; tambien da error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para retornar un valor debes esperar a que el request sea completado, para ello debes implementar algo llamado promises documentate sobre el tema

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise